# How do you prove that the sum of 1 to k divided by k is a multiple of 1/2?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Expressed mathematically: $\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k n = \frac{x}{2}$ where x is an integer. I tested this series mathematically and I found this trend, but I don't know how to actually prove it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be aware of the fact that $$\sum_{i=1}^k i = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$ Knowing this, your statement is obvious.

Comment: What is the average of $1,2,3,......k$  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an easy and well-known result that 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k i=\frac{k(k+1)}2. 
$$
For a not very formal but very intuitive proof, write 
$$
\begin{array}{rccccccccc}
S&=&1&+&2&+&3&+&\cdots&+&k-1&+&k\\
S&=&k&+&(k-1)&+&\cdots&+&3&+&2&+&1
\end{array}
$$
If you now add both rows, you get 
$$
2S=(k+1)+(k+1)+\cdots+(k+1)=k(k+1).
$$

Comment: the index should be $n$ and not $i$.

Comment: Good catch, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\frac 1k \sum\limits_{n=1}^k n$ is, by definition the average of $1,2,3,4......, .... k$.  Convince yourself that the average of $1....n$ (equally distributed) is $\frac {k+1}2$.

.... or ...

Let $N =  \sum\limits_{n=1}^k n = \sum\limits_{n=k;-1}^1 n = \sum\limits_{n=1}^k ((k+1) -n)$

So $2N =  (\sum\limits_{n=1}^k n) + (\sum\limits_{n=1}^k ((k+1) -n))$

$= \sum\limits_{n=1}^k [n + (k=1) - n] = \sum\limits_{n=1}^k (k+1)$

$= k*(k+1)$

So $N = \frac {k(k+1)}{2}$

.... or ....

$N = 1+2+3..........+ (k-2) + (k-1) + k$

$N = k + (k-1) + (k-2) + .....+ 3 + 2 + 1$

$N+N = (1+k) + (2+k-1) + (3k-2 ) + ........ +(k-2+3) + (k-1+2) + (k+1)$

$2N = (k+1) + (k+1) + (k+1) + ..... + (k+1) + (k+1) + (k+1)$

$2N = k*(k+1)$.

So $N = \frac {k(k+1)}2$

..... or do induction.....

$\frac 1k \sum^k n = \frac {k+1}2$ is true for $k = 1$ as $\frac 11 = \frac 22$.

$\frac 1k \sum^k n = \frac {k+1}2$ then

$\sum^k n = \frac {k(k+1)}2$

$\sum^{k+1}n = \frac {k(k+1)}2 + (k+1)$

$= \frac {k(k+1)}2 +\frac {2(k+1)}2$

$= \frac {(k+2)(k+1)}2$

So $\frac {1}{k+1} \sum^{k+1}n = \frac {k+2}2$.